# Square of integration of an integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Then prove that
$$ \Big\vert \int_{a}^b f \Big\vert^2 \leq \int_{a}^b \vert f \vert^2.$$

Comment: This is not a do-my-homework-for-me site.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality $\Big\vert \int_{a}^b f \Big\vert^2 \leq \int_{a}^b \vert f \vert^2$ is not true if $b-a >1$. Take for example the constant funtion $f=1$.

I think you have to prove $\Big\vert \int_{a}^b f \Big\vert^2 \leq (b-a)^2\int_{a}^b \vert f \vert^2.$

This can be done with $g=1$ and Cauchy- Schwarz:

$\Big\vert \int_{a}^b f \Big\vert^2 =\Big\vert \int_{a}^b fg \Big\vert^2 \leq.... $

Comment: Please explain a bit more. @Fred

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy Schwarz inequality ?

Comment: I know it for inner product space i.e.$ \vert <u,v> \vert \leq \Vert u \Vert  \Vert v \Vert$